# Retrieve a value from a matrix with multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am having difficulty retrieving a value from a matrix of values based on criteria on columns and rows. A customer has gone to a store location from their home but there are same stores closer to their home than the one visited. I want to know which store location was the closest (if two have the same distance, min of name would do).

Here is what I have:
Sheet1:

| Location | 12345 | 12346 | 12347 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5.53 | 8.68 | 18.94 |
| B | 8.72 | 5.47 | 4.73 |
| C | 6.88 | 7.28 | 4.73 |
| Each value represents distance from 'Location' to a zip code (columns) |  |  |  |

What I want is to choose the (min of name) closest location from the zip code (see below)
Sheet2:

| Zip | Location Visited | Desired Location Dist. | Desired Location Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | C | 5.53 | A |
| 12346 | A | 5.47 | A |
| 12347 | A | 4.73 | B |

Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

I tried this:

=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!$B$1:$D$1=Sheet2!$A2)x(Sheet2!$C2=Sheet1!$B$2:$D$4),0))

but returns #N/A

Answer (score 1):

In `Sheet2 C2` use: `=MIN(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$4,,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$D$1,0)))`

In `Sheet2 D2` use:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,MATCH($C2,INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$4,,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$D$1,0))))`

[image]

Comment: I implemented the formula you wrote for D2 but Excel is having difficulties matching most of the cells. Only a select few from a few thousand records match and give the correct output but the remaining error put with #N/A. Is there a more efficient way for this to work?

Comment: Does the `D2` formula error, or the `C2` one as well? In that case the ZIP is not listed in sheet1. If that's not the case, please post the formula you used. Maybe I can recognize an error in the formula you implemented.